# Refreshing the main page for no reason when entering the site

Tags: wordpress, redirect, dns, cpanel

Refreshing the main page for no reason when entering the site

I have a wordpress site
The problem is that sometimes when entering the main page of the site, it is refreshed two or three times to make it stable.
Sometimes it even redirects to my other domain which is no longer active

I did not make such settings.
Deactivating plugins and templates does not solve the problem.
The hosting support says that the problem is not ours. They scanned the host for viruses and quarantined some files.
I even installed WordPress and plugins and the template twice. I cleared the browser cache and DNS and reset the settings of Zonaditor. There are no domains or redirects in the cPanel domain. But the problem still remains.

```
`/home/megasecr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/vendor/maxmind-db/reader/ext/maxminddb.c
 /home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/stats/usage_202107.html
 /home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/stats/usage_202106.html
 /home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/logs/Jul-2021.tar.gz.3
```

/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/logs/Jul-2021.tar.gz.17
/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/logs/Jul-2021.tar.gz.13
/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/awstats/.data/awstats072021.mega-secret.com.txt
/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/awstats/.data/awstats062021.mega-secret.com.txt
/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/awstats/awstats.mega-secret.com.2107.errors404.html
/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/awstats/awstats.mega-secret.com.2107.errors403.html
/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/awstats/awstats.mega-secret.com.2106.errors404.html
/home/megasecr/domains/mega-secret.com/awstats/awstats.mega-secret.com.2106.errors403.html`

Comment: “it is refreshed two or three times to make it stable”. What do you mean by stable? What does unstable mean in this case?

Comment: I mean, it is refreshed once or twice until the page is fully loaded. The first or second time it is half-finished. www.mega-secret.com

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem myself. I am writing here, maybe it will help someone. The problem stemmed from my own amateur mistake.
I had made the wrong settings in Google Optimization. I stopped Google optimization and the problem was solved.